# Issue caching Zend_Paginator with DB profiler enabled

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-paginator

I am having a bizarre issue when trying to cache `Zend_Paginator` and having the `Zend_Db_Adapter` profiler enabled.

It creates a cache file, but each `ID` is different meaning that the cache hit will never happen.

After disabling the profiler everything works as expected. What is going on here? And is it possible to get the cache working with the profiler?

Comment: What version of Zend Framework are you using?  IIRC, this issue was fixed in 1.12.0 ([see ZF-6989](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6989))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152759/zend-paginator-and-cache-how-can-i-read-the-datas-that-i-have-sent-to-cache

Answer (score 0):

There are bug reports regarding this issue with zend Framework. Eg. this one: [ZF Bug 8731](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8731).

> The problem is that the serialized object (Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect) when Zend_Db_Profiler is enable, has also included a unique time measurement queries. So we can be 100% sure that the result of function md5() will be different every time.

This related bug has been fixed in 1.12: [ZF Bug 6989](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6989). If you can update the framework, you should.